# How to raise StopIteration repeatedly from Ruby fiber

Tags: ruby, exception, iteration, fiber

The following Ruby fiber raises a StopIteration exception the first time it is resumed, but not subsequently. Is it possible to make a fiber which raises the exception every time it is resumed?

```
f = Fiber.new do
  while true
    raise StopIteration
  end
end
```

Comment: Does the exception have to bubble up and out of the fiber's execution block?  If yes, then by definition the fiber will terminate. If not, just make use of `begin..rescue` inside the loop.

Comment: PS: `while true ... end` is better expressed in ruby as `loop do ... end`.

Comment: Yeah, it does need to bubble out of the Fiber. I was puzzled because this non-fiber function works correctly. def g; while true; raise StopIteration; end; end

Comment: Well you can certainly call a method that raises an exception repeatedly, since the method has to return anyway. If you return from the fiber's block (or terminate it with an exception), then the fiber can't be resumed... you'd have to make a new fiber.

Comment: One strange quirk about loop vs while true. Loop silently rescues StopIteration exceptions. http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/StopIteration